# Some subplot's attrbitues don't work in loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the code:

```
norm_reviews = pd.read_csv('fandango_scores.csv')

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 20))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(4, 1, 1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(4, 1, 2)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(4, 1, 3)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(4, 1, 4)

subplot_list = [ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4]
columns_for_visualization = ['Fandango_Ratingvalue', 'RT_user_norm', 'Metacritic_user_nom', 'IMDB_norm']
for i in range(0, len(subplot_list)):
    subplot_list[i] = subplot_list[i].hist(norm_reviews[columns_for_visualization[i]], bins=20, range=(0, 5))
    subplot_list[i] = subplot_list[i].set_title('Distribution ' + columns_for_visualization[i])
plt.show()
```

The problem, that the first line in loop work, but the second line doesn't work:

```
subplot_list[i] = subplot_list[i].hist(norm_reviews[columns_for_visualization[i]], bins=20, range=(0, 5))
subplot_list[i] = subplot_list[i].set_title('Distribution ' + columns_for_visualization[i])
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/ML/DataQuest/Data visualisazation/visualization.py", line 17, in <module>
    subplot_list[i] = subplot_list[i].set_title('Distribution ' + columns_for_visualization[i])
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'set_title'
```

But why the first line work? And why the second line doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work

```
for sub_plot, col_for_visualization in zip(subplot_list, columns_for_visualization):
    sub_plot.hist(norm_reviews[col_for_visualization], bins=20, range=(0, 5))
    sub_plot.set_title('Distribution ' + col_for_visualization )
plt.show()
```

The reason why your code does not work is because you actually reassign the contents of `subplot_list[i]` in your first line. By the time you get to the second line, the content is no longer an `ax` object but whatever the `hist` function returns.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution:

```
for i in range(0, len(subplot_list)):
    subplot_list[i].hist(norm_reviews[columns_for_visualization[i]], bins=20, range=(0, 5))
    subplot_list[i].set_title('Distribution ' + columns_for_visualization[i])
```